# create widget to count unread Spam email of gmail

Tags: php, email, gmail, gmail-imap, gmail-contextual-gadgets

I want to make a widget that count unread spam mail, but the script shows fullcount is 0.
when I use script for inbox its work fine

```
//function to get unread emails taking username and password as parameters
   function check_email($username, $password)
   { 
    $url = "https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/spam"; 

    // sendRequest 
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
    $curlData = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    //returning retrieved feed
    return $curlData;

   }
```

/

```
     //making page to behave like xml document to show feeds
    header('Content-Type:text/xml; charset=UTF-8');
    //header('Content-Type:text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1');
    //calling function
 echo $feed = check_email("myid@gmail.com", "mypassword");
```